# Can you combine multiple svgs with different viewBoxes and customize each in Polymer?

Tags: svg, polymer-1.0, polymer-starter-kit

I have multiple svgs that I'd like to use in my application and was hoping to put them in a single custom-svg element to reference individually by id, however, the viewBoxes are different. One svg is defined as

```
<iron-iconset-svg name="club-icon" size="512">
    <svg>
        <defs>
            <g id="club-icon">
                <path d="bunch of numbers"></path>
            </g>
        </defs>
    </svg>
</iron-iconset-svg>
```

The other svg is defined as

```
<iron-iconset-svg name="club-icon" size="300">
    <svg>
        <defs>
            <g id="book-icon">
                <path d="bunch of numbers"></path>
            </g>
        </defs>
    </svg>
</iron-iconset-svg>
```

Is there a way for each custom icon to define its own viewBox, or must every svg defined within a single iconset share the same properties. For now I have multiple custom element html files, but each custom element is an http request (which I'm trying to minimize).

Answer (score 4):

It can be done using symbols.

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" style="display: none;">

  <symbol id="beaker" viewBox="214.7 0 182.6 792">
    <!-- <path>s and whatever other shapes in here -->  
  </symbol>

  <symbol id="shape-icon-2" viewBox="0 26 100 48">
    <!-- <path>s and whatever other shapes in here -->  
  </symbol>

</svg>
```

See this article on CSS tricks for a further explanation.

https://css-tricks.com/svg-symbol-good-choice-icons/

Comment: This note (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/symbol) seems pertinent: `Note: A <symbol> element itself is not meant to be rendered. Only instances of a <symbol> element (i.e., a reference to a <symbol> by a <use> element) are rendered. That means that some browsers could refuse to directly display a <symbol> element even if the CSS display property tells otherwise.`

Comment: Adding to the previous comment. All one needs to do is add the following below those symbol references: `<use xlink:href='#beaker' /><use xlink:href='#shape-icon-2' />` to make use of `symbol`s properly. Link above mentions symbols are intended to be templates used/referenced.

Answer (score 0):

you might try a transform scale on you g element?

```
<g id="book-icon" transform="scale(1.71)">
```

1.71 = 512/300

or if you are using gulp/grunt, you could resize the SVGs to be the same using svg-scaler or the like